# Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, object, foreach, fetch

on Control page:

```
<?php
  include 'pages/db.php'; 
  $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sidemenu WHERE `menu_id`='".$menu."' ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1", $con);
  $sidemenus = mysql_fetch_object($results);
?>
```

on View Page:

```
<?php foreach ($sidemenus as $sidemenu): ?>
  <?php echo $sidemenu->mname."<br />";?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Error is:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\phone\pages\init.php on line 22

Can you fix it? I don't have any idea what happened.

Comment: `$sidemenu` is not an object. `var_dump()` it and see what it is.

Comment: #22 is `<?php echo $sidemenu->mname."<br />";?>`

Comment: You should check your mysql query is not erroring.  `$menu` might be an empty string.  That would cause your `$sidemenu` to not be an object.

Comment: Query working well and returning datas.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check the manual for [`mysql_fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php). It returns an object, not an array of objects.

I'm guessing you want something like this

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sidemenu WHERE `menu_id`='".$menu."' ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1", $con);

$sidemenus = array();
while ($sidemenu = mysql_fetch_object($results)) {
    $sidemenus[] = $sidemenu;
}
```

---

Might I suggest you have a look at PDO. `PDOStatement::fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` does what you assumed `mysql_fetch_object()` to do

Answer (score 10):

#### Your error

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\phone\pages\init.php on line 22

#### Your comment

> @22 is `<?php echo $sidemenu->mname."<br />";?>`

`$sidemenu` is not an object, and you are trying to access one of its properties.

That is the reason for your error.

Answer (score 5):

`$sidemenu` is not an `object`, so you can't call methods on it. It is probably not being sent to your `view`, or `$sidemenus` is empty.

Comment: isn't `mysql_fetch_object` returns set of objects?

Comment: @Gerelt No, I suggest you check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) again.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php foreach ($sidemenus->mname as $sidemenu): ?>
<?php echo $sidemenu ."<br />";?>
```

or

```
$sidemenus = mysql_fetch_array($results);
```

then

```
<?php echo $sidemenu['mname']."<br />";?>
```