# SQL Ranking with multiple columns

Tags: php, sql, ranking

I'm making a leaderboard with rankings. Its using SQL to get the data. Now I'm wondering, how can I actually let it rank?

For example:

> `Name:`      `Wins:`      `Points:`      `Skills:`
>   `Matt`       `1`           `2009`        `2`
>   `Mark`       `4`       2014        8

How can I let PHP calculate what is at top and give it a rank? So that "Mark" will be at the first line because he has the most points and give it rank 1. And "Matt" at line 2 with rank 2?

Comment: You need to do it with php or sql?

Comment: I would go for a query which will be much easier than doing it in php. But we need to see the query you have.

Comment: Here is the complete code:
https://gist.github.com/matthijs110/6d3db4c5a5a43699f58c

The tables are different then my example. But the highest wins points needs to be at top and the highest one needs to get Rank 1,the  the next highest rank 2.

Comment: Your query says `ORDER BY Wins DESC`, so the result shown here doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT name,Wins,Points,Skills,@rn := @rn + 1 as Rank
FROM TableName, (SELECT @rn := 0 ) r
ORDER BY points DESC
```

Result (with the given data):

```
NAME    WINS    POINTS  SKILLS  RANK
Mark    4       2014    8       1
Matt    1       2009    2       2
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffd324/2).

Comment: I get this error then:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Minecraft-User-Info/leaderboard/index.php on line 86

Line 86:
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

Comment: @Matt: See [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891911/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in MySQL like this

```
select t.*, 
       @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
from your_table t
cross join (select @rank := 0) r
order by points desc
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work :/
https://gist.github.com/matthijs110/524f2e19a5dc7ebac290

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention DBMS, and the mysql trick presented above does not work, so I assume a DBMS with support for OLAP (psql, db2, oracle, mssql among other supports them)

`select name,Wins,Points,Skills
 from (
    SELECT name,Wins,Points,Skills
         , rank() over (order by points desc) as rnk
    FROM TableName
 ) 
 order by rnk`

Comment: It mentions xampp in the comments