# Trying to get property of non-object in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

First of all I know that it might be a duplicate question but I did some search for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891911/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in) but I couldn't understand how it works.

I have this code...

```
<?php
$host       = "localhost";
$user       = "root";
$pass       = "Passw0rd";
$database   = "test";

$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$database}", $user, $pass);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE fname LIKE :q OR lname LIKE :q");
$stmt->bindValue(':q', '%'.$_GET['q'].'%');
$stmt->execute();

while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    echo '<a href="members2.php?view=' . $row->id . '" target="_blank">' . $row->fname . ' ' . $row->lname . '</a><br/>';
}
?>
```

And I get this error

```
Trying to get property of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\ptixiaki\livesearch.php on line 13
```

Line 13 is this line ...

```
echo '<a href="members2.php?view=' . $row->id . '" target="_blank">' . $row->fname . ' ' . $row->lname . '</a><br/>';
```

Can you help me to fix that

Comment: You may want to use `fetchObject()` instead of `fetch()`, otherwise you get an array, and not an object.

Comment: @ClémentMalet Thank you it fixed something but now I get this `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$id in E:\xampp\htdocs\ptixiaki\livesearch.php on line 13`

Comment: Try `$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);print_r($result);` to see what is the result returned.

Comment: @ClémentMalet I fixed the second  error . Write your first comment as an answer in order to accept it

Comment: As @ClémentMalet said using `fetchObject()` allows you to do this `$row->id` and with `fetch()` you can do this `$row['id']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `fetchObject()` instead of a regular `fetch()` to specify that you want to treat the row as an object (and use its properties), and not as an array.