# Trying to get property of non-object $this->handleViewException($e, $obLevel);

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes

When I click on the some links I got this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/klshe/public_html/app/views/site/market/admin.blade.php)

```
// an exception is thrown. This prevents any partial views from leaking.
    try
    {
        include $__path;
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        $this->handleViewException($e, $obLevel);
    }
```

but the links work fine at the localhost, what is the problem please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to get property of non-object in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891911/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in)

Comment: Maybe your array is not an object.

Comment: Can I see the code in your admin view?