# Trying to get property of non-object when used on object

Tags: php

I have some PHP that is returning an object to a variable:

```
                $db = new Db(); 
                $db->db_connect(); 
                $testSelectQuery = $db->db_select('SELECT * FROM test');
                //$dbValue = $testSelectQuery[0]->testcol;
                $test = $testSelectQuery[0];
                FB::log($test);
```

Here is the output of $test:

```
Object {idtest: "1", testcol: "from db"}
```

Now when I try to echo one of the columns:

```
echo $test->testcol
```

I get an error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

It was just defined as an object in the output. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Edit: vardump($test) results in: `array(2) { ["idtest"]=> string(1) "1" ["testcol"]=> string(7) "from db" }`

Comment: Where exactly do you try to echo a property? I don't see the code.

Comment: right after FB::log($test);

Comment: And what does `FB::log` do?

Comment: When I am getting such an error, most of the time the database result is just empty ;-) Did you check on that?

Comment: @DavidTunnell did you try `$test['testcol']`

Comment: `$test` isn't an object.  It's an array.

Comment: I added the vardump. FB is just a PHP debugger http://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-php-code-with-firephp/

Comment: @meda Your solution fixed the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to get property of non-object in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891911/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `$test` is an associative array

Access it like this:

```
echo $test['testcol'];
```