# Laravel issue- "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: laravel

Controller :

```
$args = array();
$args['name'] = "Robin";
$args['email'] = "asdasd@asdasd.net";
$clientpayments = Payments::getPaymentByClient($id);
$args['activity'] = $clientpayments;
return view('clients.show',["args" => $args]);
```

View:

```
{{ $args->name }}
{{ $args->email }}

@if (isset($args['activity']))        
@foreach ($args['activity'] as $act)
{{$act->job_name}}
@endforeach
@endif;
```

So what the issue is is that $activity loop works fine but the $name and $email is returning a non-object error... Any ideas to where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: An array is not an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to get property of non-object in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891911/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using an array, change this:

```
{{ $args->name }}
{{ $args->email }}
```

To:

```
{{ $args['name'] }}
{{ $args['email'] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an object value, but you are sending an array to your view.

```
$payments = Payments::getPaymentByClient($id);

$args = array([
  'name' => 'Robin',
  'email' => 'asdasd@asdasd.net',
  'activity' => $payments, // Expecting a collection
]);

return view('clients.show', [
  "args" => (object) $args // Cast into an object
]);
```

**Blade template (if you have an object)**

```
{{ $args->name }}
{{ $args->email }}

// If your activity is a collection
@foreach ($args->activity as $act)
  {{ $act->job_name }}
@endforeach
```

**Blade template (if you have an array)**

```
{{ $args['name'] }}
{{ $args['email'] }}

// If your activity is a collection
@foreach ($args['activity'] as $act)
  {{ $act->job_name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

A silly mistake, but I'm just learning Laravel. I was including $args in the View rather than just $name, $email and $activity which worked perfectly.

Thanks anyway.