# Counting job applied person

Tags: php, mysql

There are 3 tables:

```
1.users (id_user, name)
2.job_post (id_post,id_company,jobtitle)
3.apply_job_post(id_apply, id_post,id_user)
```

how to count particular job applied person - any one can help me

Comment: What approaches have you tried already?

Comment: Have you tried using COUNT and GROUP BY in same query?

Comment: no sir.how to share image

Comment: select count user_id group by post_id I think

Comment: SELECT * FROM job_post INNER JOIN apply_job_post ON job_post.id_jobpost=apply_job_post.id_jobpost INNER JOIN users ON users.id_user=apply_job_post.id_user WHERE apply_job_post.id_company='2' AND id_apply='2'

Comment: only one person name will be displayed... any one can help me

Answer (score 0):

You need count and group them

```
select id_user,count(id_post) from users
left join apply_job_post on apply_job_post.id_user = users.id_user
left join job_post on apply_job_post.id_post = job_post.id_post
group by users.id_user
```

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score -1):

If you want to fetch the count of users get assigned a particular job
 then use the following query:

```
SELECT
    count(u.id_user)
FROM apply_job_post AJP
LEFT JOIN job_post JP ON JP.id_post=AJP.id_post
LEFT JOIN users U ON AJP.id_user=U.id_user
where JP.id_post=2
```

If you want to fetch how many jobs assigned to one particular user then you can use the following query:

The following example shows how many jobs assigned to `id_user=1`

```
SELECT
    count(u.id_user)
FROM apply_job_post AJP
LEFT JOIN job_post JP ON JP.id_post=AJP.id_post
LEFT JOIN users U ON AJP.id_user=U.id_user
where u.id_user=1
```

If you want to fetch whole data from three tables then:

```
SELECT
    U.*,
    JP.*,
    AJP.*
FROM apply_job_post AJP
LEFT JOIN job_post JP ON JP.id_post=AJP.id_post
LEFT JOIN users U ON AJP.id_user=U.id_user
```

Comment: for example,   two person can applied particular job ..only one person name will be display ....

Comment: @Selvam Deepak The query works correctly and the problem is you are trying to get property of non-object. Run this query at your database query console you should get the count.

Comment: how to get the non property object..i dn't know sir help me sir

Comment: are you sure $_SESSION[id_company] and $_GET[id] contains values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891911/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in check this one

Comment: could please update your question with the code you have written so far?

Comment: Check your mail inbox