# Podio PHP Issue

Tags: php, podio

Hello Everyone and Podio Development team, I have some issues in podio since few days, I integrate podio in client project and project is in PHP Codeigniter, The podio API's were working before perfectly, but now there are some issues i am getting error The path '/item/basic' was not found.." Request URL: http://api.podio.com/item/basic

Although to verify code, I already checked old codes which was also integrated in podio and they are also not working now since few days. I checked podio website for Podio Items: Get item basic
https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-basic-item-61768
this is deprecated but no alternatives are provided and I am getting error regarding this.

When i comment code of podio and website works but when i uncomment code of podio and run it it shows error since few days, I have tried all steps and cross check in case code mistake there is no mistake as same code was working before, old codes also i checked which worked before not worked now. Kindly help me thank you.
Attaching screenshots

> Fatal error: Uncaught PodioNotFoundError: "No matching operation could be found. The path '/item/basic' was not found.." Request URL: http://api.podio.com/item/basic Stack Trace: #0 /home/username/public_html/podio-php-4.3.0/lib/Podio.php(351): Podio::request('GET', '/item//basic', Array, Array) #1 /home/username/public_html/podio-php-4.3.0/models/PodioItem.php(120): Podio::get('/item//basic', Array) #2 /home/username/public_html/st_application/controllers/user.php(1459): PodioItem::get_basic(NULL) #3 /home/username/public_html/st_application/controllers/user.php(901): User->podioPropertyCreate(336, Array, Array, Array, Array, '3 Females, 1 Ma...', 'uploads/files/', Array, 'jahanzeb@gmail....') #4 [internal function]: User->add_property('add') #5 /home/username/public_html/st_system/core/CodeIgniter.php(360): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #6 /home/username/public_html/index.php(202): require_once('/home
>   /username...') #7 {main} thrown in /home/username/public_html/podio-php-4.3.0/lib/Podio.php on line 324

This is the issue image:
[image: This is the issue image]

Comment: Looking at the doc, the API endpoint is `/item/{item-id}/basic`

Comment: the problem is i am passing client id, secret id etc. so i am not calling specifically url, it is calling through podio client which i put in my project folder

Comment: One more thing, it was working few days ago same code same everything, now it is not working, i have 3 4 codes as you know we develop new features of websites every day so all backups also not working since few days

Comment: Can you help me with this @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Honestly, if they have an API that used to work and just stopped without you changing anything, you should contact their support directly. SO isn't meant as a general helpdesk/support forum for off-site/third party services. If you're having some programming issues with _your_ code, we're here to help you.

Comment: try just to remove **basic** from `/item/{item-id}/basic` and call another endpoint `/item/{item-id}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to get property of non-object in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891911/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in)

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the `item_id` with the API call.

[image]

For `PodioItem::get_basic` API call, the `item_id` parameter (first parameter) is **required** one.

Also, please note that this [**`get_basic` operation is deprecated and will be removed soon**](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-basic-item-61768).

Please use [Podio Get Item](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-22360) API instead.

Comment: Can you tell me where do i find item id? As i am calling id's i dont have item id, here is my sample code which was working before in get_basic when its required only 1 parameter.

  kindly check the code i called item_id and save it in userItemid with array and it was working before but now its not working as the api changed? and multiple parameters should be passed? but where do i get item_id now? because i dont see item_id in podio dashboard.
Kindly check the code and let me know what should i do.
Thank you
Check the code in next comment.

Comment: $userItemId = $getItems[0]->item_id;
        $item = PodioItem::get_basic($userItemId);


   PodioItemField::update($userItemId, $AdvertFieldId,  $field->as_json(false));
        if($itemsAdvert){

            return true;
        }