# PHP MVC Count function and pass to view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, count

Just trying to get my head around MVC and having a little trouble with counting the amount of widgets in the database.

I am not sure if this is what is screwing it up but on my index page I have this

```
        <?php require APPROOT . '/views/inc/header.php'; ?>

          Some Other stuff here

        <?php require APPROOT . '/views/inc/widget.php'; ?>
```

Model

```
        <?php
     class Widget {
        private $db;

        public function __construct(){
          $this->db = new Database;
        }

        public function countWidgets(){
          $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM widgets WHERE id=id");
          $count = $this->db->rowCount();
           }
```

Controller

```
<?php
         class Widgets extends Controller{
            public function __construct(){
              // Load Models
              $this->widgetModel = $this->model('Widget');
            }

        public function widget(){
              $count = $this->widgetModel->countWidgets();
              $data = [
                'count' => $count
              ];
              $this->view('inc/widget', $data);
            }  
        }
```

And View

```
<div class="media-body text-right">
  <h2 class="text-white"><?php echo $count->id; ?></h2>
  <span>Total Widgets</span>
</div>
```

All I seem to get is this error
Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\views\inc\widget.php on line 29

If anyone can give me a pointer where I am going wrong it would be much much appreciated, and thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Thanks
Molly

Comment: `rowCount()`, I assume, it returning an integer not an object.  Also, you aren't `return`ing anything from the Model to the Controller so `$count` is never populated in the Controller. For these reasons, there isn't a property named `id` in `$count`. Moreover, `id=id` is an absolutely useless WHERE clause condition since it will not filter out any rows. If you need a `$count->id` value, you will need to generate an object from the result set (not count how many rows are in the result set), then your View will stop barking back at you.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic typo since this mistake/misunderstanding is not likely to help future researchers.  This page could also be easily closed as a duplicate of MANY pages such as https://stackoverflow.com/q/5891911/2943403